# Gratis en tant qu'adverbe et adjectif

Tags: vocabulaire, adjectifs, adverbes

(Adjectif)

> Logiciel gratis.

vs

> Logiciel gratuit.

Quelle est la différence ?

(Adverb)

> Ce médecin traite ses patients gratis.

vs

> Ce médecin traite ses patients gratuitement.

Même question.

En tant qu'adjectif, pourquoi gratis est invariable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu réalises bien la différence entre ta première phrase où *gratis* est employé **adjectivement** et la seconde ou il est employé comme **adverbe**.

Historiquement gratis est d'abord (XVe) un adverbe.
*gratis* ne signifie pas d'abord *gratuit* mais bien *gracieusement* (adverbe lui aussi) et un adverbe, en français est : invariable.

Il ne s'adjective que tardivement (XIXe). Et conservera donc son invariabilité par habitude.

Les deux propositions dans chacun de tes rectangles disgracieusement jaunis ;) signifient donc très exactement la même chose.

Mes potes et moi préférons néanmoins lui garder une fonction adverbiale. C'est encore à dire que nous dirons que *je contribue ici gratis* plus volontiers que *ma contribution ici est gratis*. ;)

Comment: Merci. Cependant il existe des adverbes qui sont variables et en fait d'origine adjectivale (tout, grand, large, droit) :

Comment: https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/grammaire/adverbes-variables.php  ;  https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/regles-orthographe/tout-enervee-ou-toute-enervee/

Comment: @dimitri : Oui, tu as raison, certains adverbes peuvent être fléchi... ceux... d'origine adjectivale. Avec *gratis* c'est l'inverse qui s'est produit. L'adjectif est d'origine adverbiale et 4 siècles passent entre les deux.

Answer (score 2):

The first big difference is about popularity.

*Gratuit* has been more popular than *gratis* since centuries and the trend is highly in favor of the former.

[image]

There is also the colloquial/slang *gratos* which usage is slightly raising (and the spoken French usage is likely higher than what books analysis exhibits):

[image]

Another difference is the type of usage. I'm not sure of the truthfulness of Google Ngram classification algorithms but it detects extremely low uses of *gratis* as an adjective, up to **one thousand less** than adverb use:

[image]

The trend is also to in favor of *gratuitement* against *gratis* (*gratuitement* is used 12 times more nowadays):

[image]

This, combined with fact the *gratis* ends with an *s* so wouldn't change between singular and plural anyway makes **gratisse* unlikely to appear.

Same for *gratos* and an hypothetical **gratosse*...

Comment: +1. One of the cases that I don't know which answer to choose:-)! Merci !

Comment: De rien ! Je ne sais pas pourquoi j'ai répondu en anglais...